# How to update ListView when my class extends of GetView

Tags: flutter

I am trying to update my ListView when I click on the FloatingActionButton but nothing happens, I am using the Get library where I have my controller but I don't know why it is not updated I am new to this, can someone help me?

```
    class HistorialPage extends GetView<HistorialController> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: SelectColor.parseColor("16acac"),
        child: new Icon(Icons.sync),
        onPressed: (){
          controller.getList();
        },
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: SelectColor.parseColor("#16acac"),
        child: Center(
          child:Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: Center(
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: SelectColor.parseColor("#fff"),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
                          topRight: Radius.circular(30.0),
                        )
                    ),
                    child:
                    Center(
                      child:  GetBuilder<HistorialController>(
                        builder: (controller){
                          return LoadingOverlay(
                            isLoading: controller.isLoading,
                            child: ListView.builder(
                                itemCount: controller.postsList.length,
                                itemBuilder: (context,index) =>
                                HistorialItems(post: controller.postsList[index],
                                ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

HistorialController this is the code of my controller which I call above and I have the method in which it is updated

```
    class HistorialController extends GetxController{
  List<Post> postsList=[];
  bool isLoading = true;
  @override
  void onInit() {
      getList();
    super.onInit();
  }

  void getList(){
    PostsProvider().getPostsList(
        beforeSend: (){
          print('success');
        },
        onSuccess: (posts){
          postsList.addAll(posts.reversed.toList());
          isLoading =false;
          update();
        },
        onErrror: (error){
          isLoading =false;
          update();
          print(error);
        });

    update();
  }
}
```

Comment: I already managed to update my ListView, but I don't know how my LoadingOverlay is nothing more than CircularProgressIndicator
run when I update my ListView